# Magento 2.3.4: Product Views Report Not Working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, reports, recently-viewed, mostview-product-collection

I am using Magento 2.3.4, I have issue with product view reports. All reports are working well, except product view.

I have checked Time Zone as well as refreshed statistics lifetime. I tried all possible ways, but I am not getting  any result. I also checked in relevant in database which remain  empty. Also report_event table is empty all the time. For more info please check the screenshots attached below.

- **1) Dashboard Most Viewed Products are Empty.**

[image: enter Dashboard Most Viewed Products are Empty]

- **2) Product Viewed Reports Empty**

[image: enter Product Viewed Reports Empty]

- **3) Statistics Lifetime Refreshed**

[image: enter Statistics Lifetime Refreshed]

- **4) All relevant tables remain empty**

[image: enter report view product index]

[image: enter report view product aggregated yearly]

[image: enter report view product aggregated monthly]

[image: enter report view product aggregated daily]

Comment: same issue in magento 2.3.5

Comment: you got any sollution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I got the sollution for this, Goto
Store -> Setting -> Configuration -> General ->Reports ->
General Report

Enable

[image]

Then refresh statistics and clear cache then ,ready to go
Thanks